# ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error. VS2010 + Oracle ODP.NET

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, odp.net

Both x32 and x64 Oracle Clients (11.2.0) coexist in my development computer for compatibility with my application (that is x64) and Visual Studio.
ORA-12560 error occures if I add new connection in VS2010 using "Oracle ODP.NET" data data provider. Everything works fine if '.NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle' is being used.

Any ideas where the problem might be?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: X32 and X64 are being used as Oracle Homes?

Comment: Yes. Both path are used as Oracle Home.

Comment: So when you do from say command prompt and type sqlplus which Oracle it is taking?

Comment: I think x64 as it is first in PATH

Comment: FYI. Problem is being solved. ODP.NET's registry settings are located under HKLM\Software\Oracle\ODP.NET\ and after I changed path to Oracle.DataAccess.dll there from x64 to x32 folder it started working as expected